# Question about $\epsilon' \epsilon$ in the linear regression model

Tags: regression

While studying the standard multivariate linear regression model, I came across the following:

[image]

Could anyone please explain me why the last equality holds, and, why $Z(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'$ cannot simply be simplified to $I$ (isn't it true that $Z(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'=ZZ^{-1}Z'^{-1}Z'=II=I$?

Comment: The trace is invariant under cyclic permutations.

Comment: [$tr(AB)=tr(BA)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29#Trace_of_a_product)

Comment: student; ocram beat me to the punch, with an even more general result (though it's a consequence of the one I mentioned, since you can replace either $A$ or $B$ with arbitrary products and get the result that it's true for cyclic permutations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question has been answered by Glen_b in his comment. Regarding your second question, $\matrix{Z}$ is not (generally) square, hence it does not have an inverse. $\matrix{Z}'\matrix{Z}$ on the other hand is square and can be inverted.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)! That's exactly what I needed to know.